# Map with empty values are omitted by default

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, map

Below is the way I store the keys and values in my map.

```
Map<String, Object> mapNew = new Map<String, Object>();
Object obj = record.get(fieldName) != null ? record.get(fieldName) : null;    
mapNew.put(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel(), obj); // contains field label and corresponding field value
```

Response in system.debug is

```
recordDetail={Account Name=Test, Active=true, Business Phone=null, Email=abc@gmail.com, Title=Mr.}
```

But when I am printing the same map on the javascript side, response looks like this,

```
Account Name: "Test"
Active: true
Email: "kommurikrishnateja@gmail.com"
Title: "Mr."
```

I want to know why the key with an empty value entry gets omitted automatically and how to handle this issue in javascript side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specifics as to why key's with null values in maps are omitted when passing data to the client, but, a simple enough operation would be to convert your map to a string. Then, from the client, when receiving the server payload, simply use [JSON.parse(variable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in order to convert back to an object.

Comment: The above trick worked. Thanks @glls